# How to write Ansible conditional for loop

Tags: ansible

I have a file in `/tmp/nodescount.txt` and it has some values like below:

```
instance-one
instance-two
instance-three
```

I need to read this file `line-by-line` and and execute another task when a condition is satisfied.

So I did this:

```
---
- hosts: all_nodes
  tasks:

 - name: Get the existing node names
   with_lines: cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
   register: node_names    


 - name: Join the minions
   become: true
   shell: |
     cd /tmp/
     ./join.sh
   when: ansible_hostname != node_names # should loop over each node_name (instance-one, instance-two, instance-three)
```

So I want to run `Join the minions` task only when `ansible_hostname` value in that particular node is not equals to any of the three values (instance-one, instance-two, instance-three).

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Where is the file /tmp/nodescount.txt? Is it on the controller?  Or, is it on each of the remote hosts?

Comment: it is on each of remote hosts called all_nodes

Comment: See my answer. Is this what you want? It would be good to comment on the use-case. It seems like you want to control the script on the remote hosts by a file distributed separately. Where do such files come from? Are the files all the same? Probably there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the looping should happen in `Join the minions` task. I.e. in one task read file contents, then loop over the lines in the file on the next task.

Example:

```yaml
- hosts: all_nodes

  tasks:
  - name: Get the existing node names
    command: cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
    register: node_names
  - name: Join the minions
    shell: ./join.sh
    args:
      chdir: /tmp
    when: ansible_hostname != item
    loop: "{{ node_names.stdout_lines }}"
    become: true
```

Comment: this gives the error: `cat: /tmp/nodescount.txt: No such file or directory` even though it is there. So I removed `become: true` and it again says the same error. for now, I have only one line in that file. But I guess it is not the problem

Comment: Number of lines in file should not matter. Are you able to `cat` the file with the same user as the one being used for playbook?

Comment: Oh i think `with_lines` doesn't work for remote hosts. it executes locally

Comment: That's correct. I just noticed your comment on the original question. Answer updated, you would definitely need two tasks instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Given the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[all_nodes]
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

and the files on the remote hosts

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_01 cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
test_01
test_02

shell> ssh admin@test_02 cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
test_01
test_02

shell> ssh admin@test_03 cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
test_01
test_02
```

The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: all_nodes
  tasks:
    - command: cat /tmp/nodescount.txt
      register: node_names
    - debug:
        msg: Join the minions
      when: inventory_hostname not in node_names.stdout_lines
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
skipping: [test_01]
skipping: [test_02]
ok: [test_03] => 
  msg: Join the minions
```